# 4.6.12 to 4.7.1 upgrade causes problems with directories, update paths and clear cache

Tags: 4.7, upgrade, cache

This issue has been asked in two other threads specifically:

**4.6.10 to 4.7.1 upgrade woes**
[4.6.10 to 4.7.1 upgrade woes](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9408/4-6-10-to-4-7-1-upgrade-woes/9470#comment9356_9470)

**Upgrade to 4.7.1 results in blank page**
[Upgrade to 4.7.1 results in blank page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/upgrade-to-4-7-1-results-in-blank-page#comment9517_9445)

I am asking this in a new thread so I can post images of what I am seeing as I am having the same problem.  I did an update in my test region, and did not click on Clean Up Cache or Update Paths buttons (otherwise it goes blank) and found some other issues.  This issue is preventing me from updating myproduction site.

Directories - gets an error page  [image: Upload Directories error]
Clean up Cache and Update Paths 
Paths disappear and clicking on either of the two buttons with blank out CiviCRM on front and back end.  [image: Clean up Cache and update paths]
Joomla-CiviCRM integration goes blank
[image: Joomla Integration]
For reference I am on Joomla 3.4.8, CiviCRM 4.6.12, PHP 5.5.25.  I cleaned all the caches, validated paths prior to updating.  Deleting Config.IDS.ini and en_US do not make a difference.

Here is the entire content of the directories error that came back:

CiviCRM-001

**RuntimeException: "Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path""**

```
#0 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(475): Civi\Core\Paths->getVariable("cms.root", "path") #1 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/function.crmResPath.php(55): CRM_Core_Resources->getPath("cms.root", NULL) #2 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%E8/E8B/E8BB6A67%%Path.hlp.php(11): smarty_function_crmResPath((Array:1), Object(CRM_Core_Smarty)) #3 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1264): include("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%E8/E8B/E8...") #4 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(194): Smarty->fetch("CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Path.hlp", NULL, NULL, FALSE) #5 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/function.help.php(64): CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch("CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Path.hlp") #6 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0F/0FF/0FF13161%%Path.tpl.php(9): smarty_function_help((Array:1), Object(CRM_Core_Smarty)) #7 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1907): include("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0F/0FF/0F...") #8 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php(19): Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2)) #9 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1907): include("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0C...") #10 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EAA96A89%%joomla.tpl.php(86): Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2)) #11 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1264): include("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EA...") #12 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(194): Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/joomla.tpl", NULL, NULL, FALSE) #13 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(133): CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/joomla.tpl") #14 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(99): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path)) #15 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path), "display") #16 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path), "display") #17 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display") #18 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run() #19 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", "Directories", NULL) #20 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13)) #21 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4)) #22 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(116): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4)) #23 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke() #24 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(392): require_once("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...") #25 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(372): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...") #26 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm") #27 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(152): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch() #28 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(252): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute() #29 /home/hetclub/public_html/hettest/administrator/index.php(47): JApplicationCms->execute() #30 {main}
```

@import url(http://hettest.hetclub.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(http://hettest.hetclub.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path"

[Return to home page.](http://hettest.hetclub.org/administrator/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: I turned on the logging and looked at the console in Firefox.  This is the error I got when I clicked on reset paths:                                                      
"The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."                   I also received the following on that page: Empty string passed to getElementById(). jquery.min.js:2:24487

Comment: I was able to turn the white screens back to CiviCRM by manually entering paths in to the CiviCRM Settings Overrides specifically 1. $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['customFileUploadDir']  2. $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['uploadDir']  3. $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir']  and entered the root in 4. define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR',

Comment: When I clicked on Reset Paths it gave me this message.  "Beginning site move process...
WARNING: The setting (uploadDir) is overridden and could not be reverted.
WARNING: The setting (customFileUploadDir) is overridden and could not be reverted.
WARNING: The setting (extensionsDir) is overridden and could not be reverted.
Template cache and upload directory have been cleared.
Database cache tables cleared.
Session has been reset."

Comment: Upon further analysis, it appears I only need to manually set the extensions directory 1. $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'], but I am still getting the error on the Upload Directories.  I am getting a "ReferenceError: CRM is not defined" in Firefox Console

Comment: Hi Hudson! This is Bruce from the other thread. I noticed that in the database table civicirm_domain that the field config_backend went missing. I manually entered it back in but no avail.

Comment: I'm having the same issues on the same fields, too, Hudson. Gonna try to track down the issue. Did you file a bug report in Jira?

Comment: I think there already is one :https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17973.  I think the issue with paths is causing the blank screens, the directories screen to not have a root path, etc...

Comment: Doing some additional testing.  If I load 4.7.2 and then click Reset paths, I get a WSOD.  By setting the override path for just the CiviCRM Extensions Directory in administrator - > civicrm.settings.php, I regain my backend CiviCRM control panel. This does not fix the issue with cms.root.path error when trying to display Directories screen.

Comment: (Edit the file administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Pa‌​th.hlp to replace the first crmResPath with crmResURL)
Great this works for me, Joomla 3.8.2 , civicrm 4.7.24

Answer (score 1):

So this was solved by adding the manual extensions directory in (adding the manual path in both civicrm.settings.php - $civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] and the Directories page issue was solved using this: 
[cms.root.path error after upgrade to 4.7 (Joomla)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/cms-root-path-error-after-upgrade-to-4-7-joomla).  (Edit the file administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Pa‌​th.hlp to replace the first crmResPath with crmResURL)

Comment: I'm not following you here Hudson. Can you clarify this a bit as to what "manual extensions directory" you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: In both civicrm.settings.php files you can manually set the path.  They are normally commented out, but in this case you uncomment the global_settings line and then uncomment out the line you want to set manually.  The extensions directory in this case is the path to where your extensions directory is located.  My path is /home/my site/public_html/media/civicrm/extensions/.  Does that help?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  I have the same issue running Joomla under Windows, but it may be unique to me.  I have generated a fix, but if it is unique to me, it isn't worth adding to the codebase in view of the testing needed.

Comment: @StephenPalmstrom  It has not been a problem lately but I also use full URLs in my paths.

Comment: I am trying to get a PR that I believe solves the problem through the system - case CRM-19453.  Would you be interested in testing it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I had to get a test instance loaded to make sure that Reset Paths was still causing issues.  It is.  I would be happy to test.